# Replaceing mysqli query in while loop with one query using JOIN

Tags: php, mysqli

I often read that mysql(i) queries used in while loops are not really performance friendly and I'm going to rewrite my code because I think it get better. But here's my question if a JOIN can work here. It's a single post viewing function but you should see every comment which got posted below. I got the comment loop in the loop which the post is printed.

```
<?php 
$result = (empty($_GET['hash'])) ? $_GET['hash'] = '' : mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `userposts` WHERE `hash`='".$_GET['hash']."' LIMIT 1");
  while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  //Output of single post
    $commentresult = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `postid`='".$rows['id']."'");
    while($commentrows = mysqli_fetch_array($commentresult)){
    //Output of all comments
    }
}
```

So I think it gets better but the query with JOIN should be like:

```
 $result = (empty($_GET['hash'])) ? $_GET['hash'] = '' : mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `userposts` JOIN comments ON userposts.id = comments.postid WHERE `hash`='".$_GET['hash']."' LIMIT 1");
```

But if I'm trying to post the data of the comments in the while loop which is the singlepost printed it just prints one comment. So what can I do?

regards

Comment: Remove " LIMIT 1" from the end?

Comment: Oh, thanks that actually helped. I did it because I thought its a single post so the LIMIT 1 would be better. But this is useless because the hash is just a crypted sum of the auto increment id which is always another so there cant be double posts with same hash. Thanks.

Comment: Did this solve your issue?

Comment: Hm not at all. The single Post is printed now as often as the amount of comments. Any other ideas?

Comment: COuld you post ur table structure, so i could test and find out a solution? I don't think, that it is difficult. I have done such things before with joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a bit of a mess. You are sometimes call mysql_fetch_results with a string, which is weird.

What you want is this:

```
"SELECT * FROM comments LEFT JOIN userposts ON comments.PostID = userposts.ID WHERE userposts.Hash =  '$_GET['hash']'"
```

EDIT: sorry, you want LEFT JOIN with comments on the left. Gives you all the comments

EDIT 2: I set this up and it worked as I expected, even with multiple posts with the same hash.

```
<?php 
$hash = $_GET['hash'];
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM comments LEFT JOIN userposts ON comments.PostID = userposts.ID WHERE userposts.Hash =  '$hash'");
if ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // output of post.
    // output first comment
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
   //Output other comments
}
?>
```

Comment: The problem is I got the same output as before. I just loop the while and output it but for example I got 3 comments it output 3 times the post looks like: post - first comment - post - second comment - post - third comment

Comment: Sorry for double comment but I guess I need some query with gives me one row of the table userposts and all rows in comments which contains the hash of userposts. Is something ppossbile?

Comment: i just tested and it worked as I expected. I set up 2 tables, userposts and comments. Comments has a posted, userposts has id and hash. I inserted 2 comments with postid set the same. query by hash. I got 2 results.

Comment: And you did output every data in a while loop or only the comments?

Comment: your php code has to know what to output. Only output the comment part.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. I just didnt noticed that the first comment must be printed in the if statement.